# I am a 11 letter "single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing". Find me

Tags: word, wordplay

I am a 11 letter word

> **1, 2** - Some say my first two is about.. is about.. arghh.. leave that
>
> **3, 4, 5** - When friendship is broken, you will see some part here.
>
> **4, 5, 6** - Listen carefully.. No. No. I am not going to tell it to you.
>
> **3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8** - Do it now. You will get the answer.
>
> **7, 8, 9, 10** - If you hit that, you did that.
>
> **11** - No need if you found 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and quote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Researching

1, 2 - Some say my first two is about.. is about.. arghh.. leave that

> **Re** - used in a formal letter to mean regarding/about.

3, 4, 5 - When friendship is broken, you will see some part here.

> **sea** - "Friendship is like a sea. You can see the beginning, but you can't see the end." - Gomez

4, 5, 6 - Listen carefully.. No. No. I am not going to tell it to you.

> **ear** - which is used for listening, but we're not going to be told that.

3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 - Do it now. You will get the answer.

> **search** - To get the answer, you need to search for it.

7, 8, 9, 10 - If you hit that, you did that.

> **chin** - to chin somebody means to hit or punch them on the chin.

11 - No need if you found 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and quote.

> **researchin'** - dropping the 'g' at the end of a word and replacing it by a quote is a common part of speech.